# IIS 7.5 Permissions Confusion

Tags: permissions, iis-7.5

I am using **anonymous authentication** on my website. I have the directory structure below and I don't know how to limit permissions for each directory.

At this time, I think that I am using the default permissions provided by '**Authenticated Users**' which is excessively broad.

```
c:\myweb\myisapi.dll (limit to execute only)
c:\myweb\css\ (limit to readonly access)
c:\myweb\datafiles\ (limit access to create files/directories and to delete files)
```

Do note that the application executes fine, files and directories are created but I am very confused and hope that someone can provide me with straightforward instructions required to set the permissions as indicated above for each directory.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thank you!

P.S. Doing something simple in IIS 7 is not easy and finding how to do it is also difficult.

I'm glad that it's not me being stupid as seen in this link:
http://forums.iis.net/t/1158189.aspx?How+many+other+people+HATE+IIS7+admin+interface+

I wish that there was a concise 'idiot proof' guide availble for people who just want to wrap up something so simple.

Comment: I don't need fancy permissions, I just want an easy method of setting the above permissions for my site BTW.

Comment: So if Authenticated Users permissions are broad, what's your actual objective? Have you described what you have, or what you want? All the permissions you've listed are typically NTFS-level permissions (i.e. right click the folder, choose Permissions) - have you configured them?

Comment: Also: The default IIS anonymous user account is IUSR, unless you've reset Anonymous Auth to be the App Pool account, in which case it'll be securable as "IIS AppPool\AppPoolName" for that website/app pool.

Comment: Thank you for responding Tristank. My objective is to obtain permissions listed in the original message. I am using IUSR for anonymous authentication but if I look at any of the mentioned directories in my original post, IUSR is not listed within 'Group or user names'.  Since 'Authenticated Users' is, I assume that this is the reason that I can execute my ISAPI, read files, create directories/files and delete files without touching permissions.  Naturally, I would like to restrict permissions to my CSS folder to read only, and modify the other folder permissions as listed above.

Comment: IMPORTANT: I am not using c:\inetpub\wwwroot\... and I just noticed that creating a directory within this directory structure will 'inherit' the IIS_IUSRS group AND the 'Authenticated Users' group is no longer listed.  I guess that my easiest option is to use the inetpub directory but I would really prefer not to since I may want websites on different drives for instance.

Comment: Overcomplicating things. If you want specific permissions for a folder, you set them. If permissions for the folder you're inheriting are OK, then that's arguably OK. You simply set NTFS permissions to whatever you want them to be, for whomever you need them. Keep in mind that IUSR is Mr Anonymous, and IIS_IUSRS is "worker process identities", which aren't necessarily the same thing. So, you'd just create a folder, set permissions for IUSR to Read only, maybe Admins to Write, and ensure IIS_IUSRS has Read access as well (so web.configs can be enumerated and read). Done!

Comment: I figured that by keeping the default 'Connect As' credentials (application user pass-through authentication) I'd be keeping things as simple as possible.  If you could take a few moments to write up 'idiot proof' steps to make sure that I do this correctly, I'll test it then accept it as a correct answer.  Thank you once again for your time.

Comment: If I understand correctly, do you suggest I use IUSR to authenticate instead of 'application user' and then set IUSR permissions to the 3 folders mentioned in my original post?  Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Every worker process runs as an [Application Pool account](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tristank/archive/2011/12/22/iusr-vs-application-pool-identity-why-use-either.aspx). It does this primarily when it's booting up and not impersonating anyone.

When a request comes in and Anonymous authentication is enabled, IIS asks the request thread to impersonate the Anonymous user account (by default; IUSR) or do nothing (if you've configured Anonymous authentication to use the App Pool Account).

Let's assume there's nothing terribly interesting from an app module/routing/weirdo component thing happening, and the request

GET /something.htm

refers simply to a file on disk, within that website root. To get that much working, if you want to be absolutely permission-pathological, you would:

- Create a folder on a non-System drive
- Notionally, we're going to remove all permissions to that folder and disable inheritance to that folder, so we're starting from first principles. (if you just did that in the NTFS permissions GUI, just don't commit the change until you've got your replacement set in place, otherwise life gets Difficult)

What do you want? Well, the baseline permissions for just about any folder are:

- Administrators : Full Control
- SYSTEM : Full Control

You can arguably cut that down to other combinations, but Admins and the System can do anything anyway, so it doesn't form a strong barrier.

If you're not in one of those groups, you probably need to add your ThisSite Web Admin Group to that list.

For IIS 7 and later, you need *at least* web.config to be accessible in that location so that the worker process (prior to impersonation, so the App Pool account) can establish what the config is.

Having changed no other defaults, we can simply do this:

- IIS_IUSRS: Read

But that's a bit nonspecific and could conceivably allow another web app to read the site contents and configuration, so instead:

- IIS AppPool\App Pool Name : Read

Covers our worker process starting up and reading the configuration. Setting Read at the root of the site has the happy coincidence of making the whole site read-only, except to Admins or System (as we covered that with NTFS permissions already). So instead of looking to make things "read only", instead you're really looking to allow only specific people to write things.

Back on the subject of reads and anonymous, if the Anon account is IUSR, we'll need to add

- IUSR : Read

to any item or content we wish the anonymous user account to access, explicitly.

If the Anon account is the App Pool account, we're sorted because we added it already.

At that point:

- Request comes in for /something.htm .
- If app pool isn't running, it's demand-started as the App Pool account
- web.config is attemptedly read from the site root (and any sub-segments of the URL)
- App pool (worker thread) impersonates IUSR (or does nothing depending on anon auth setup) when request is received
- Worker thread attempts to access the requested resource

  - if successful, it returns the content
  - if unsuccessful, and HTTP authentication is configured, it prompts for credentials
  - or just fails if no auth methods are selected

--

Back to your question as asked, it looks like there may be built-in assumptions which don't hold true in every case.
In the list above, it looks like you've what looks like a meant-to-be-unreadable dump of application content beneath the site root, but something needs to have write permission to it.

If that's for "secure" information which doesn't ever get requested via the web:

- don't put it beneath the website root (everything beneath a web site root might become servable at some point through misconfiguration)
- do put it somewhere outside the site root
- don't allow anonymous users to write to it

There's also an ISAPI dll (? is it? Who calls it? Can it be installed elsewhere and script mapped instead? "no" is a legit response) which could require App Pool Account read permissions (already sorted in the list above) and might require IIS Handler Execute permission (note: not the same as NTFS read and execute permission, and you typically want to avoid Handler Execute permission for web directories as it's how people manage to upload and run scary code on the web server if not secured).

I'd love to have given you an "easy" guide to the above, but the better answer is: I don't think you necessarily want to do what you've asked how to do. If you're going to do it that way, do it that way with NTFS permissions. If it's a third party app, ask for a guide which was written for IIS 7, as 6 used overloaded terminology.